# Trouble having terminal run program through bash for loop

Tags: bash, loops, terminal

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {10..11}
do
    ./duffing -a 1 -b -1 -u 0.25 -w -1 -A 0.4 -t $i | ./stroboscopic > $i.data
done
```

The $i doesn't seem to work in the program parameter line but I get the data files.  This is the error

```
error converting i to a double for max-time:
leftover characters: i

Bad input data 
error converting i to a double for max-time:
leftover characters: i

 Bad input data
```

This is where I parse arguments in duffing program :

```
void parse_args(int argc, char **argv, state_t *state, system_t *system,
            simulation_t *simulation, int *read_initial, int *print_final)
{
    int ch;
duffing_state_t *duffing = (duffing_state_t *)system->dx_dt_state;
double dtemp;
size_t i;

while (1) {
    ch = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
    if (ch == -1)
        break;
    switch(ch) {
    case 'd':
        simulation->dt = safe_strtod(optarg, "time-step");
        break;
    case 't':
        simulation->t_max = safe_strtod(optarg, "max-time");
        break;
    case 'T':
        duffing->T = safe_strtod(optarg, "transient-time");
        break;
    case 'x':
        state->x[0] = safe_strtod(optarg, "x0");
        break;
    case 'v':
        state->x[1] = safe_strtod(optarg, "v0");
        break;
    case 'm':
        system->m = safe_strtod(optarg, "mass");
        break;
    case 'a':
        duffing->a = safe_strtod(optarg, "alpha");
        break;
    case 'b':
        duffing->b = safe_strtod(optarg, "beta");
        break;
    case 'u':
        duffing->u = safe_strtod(optarg, "mu");
        break;
    case 'w':
        duffing->w = safe_strtod(optarg, "omega");
        break;
    case 'A':
        duffing->A = safe_strtod(optarg, "amplitude");
        break;
    case 'E':
        simulation->step_fn = &euler_step;
        break;
    case 'M':
        simulation->step_fn = &midpoint_step;
        break;
    case 'R':
        simulation->step_fn = &rk4_step;
        break;
    case 'i':
        *read_initial = 1;
        break;
    case 'f':
        *print_final = 1;
        break;
    case '?':
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", ch);
    }
}

/* convert input from periods to seconds */
simulation->t_max *= 2*M_PI / duffing->w;
duffing->T *= 2*M_PI / duffing->w;

return;
}
```

I have ran the program straight from the terminal with the -t 10 so I'm pretty confused why the program is refusing to accept the input from the script.

Comment: I don't think the error here is coming from the shell. It is coming from the code inside the "duffing" script/program.  Can you post that?

Comment: turn on the shell debugging with `set -x` and you should see the place holder for `$i` being expanded into `{1..11}`, else you have a typo there OR there is something wrong with `duffing` ;-) Also, you  mean `#!/bin/bash` don't you? Good luck!

Comment: Are the data-files named `10.data` and `11.data` (as they should be), or are they named `i.data` (as you'd expect from the fact that `$i` seems to get expanded to `i` in your first command)?

Comment: The data files are named 10.data and 11.data.
I did set -x and found that the shell was not able to read the '|' and '>' piping symbols. How do I let the shell read them?

Comment: are you sure you are not using single quotes or escape characters? is this your actual script?

Comment: I got it to work.  I simply changed from bash to a regular .sh
and adjusted my loop.